# Why are compact subsets of a non-locally-compact Hausdorff topological group nowhere dense?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

In the [EOM entry](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Nowhere-dense_set) for *nowhere dense set* it is stated that

> In an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, every compact subset is nowhere dense. The same holds for infinite-dimensional Banach spaces, non-locally-compact Hausdorff topological groups, and products of infinitely many non-compact Hausdorff topological spaces.

First of all, some generalizations are possible:

1. For an infinite-dimensional Banach space, even relatively compact subsets are nowhere dense (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306257/understanding-proof-that-every-locally-compact-subset-of-c0-1-is-nowhere-den), the proof of the accepted answer also works in a general infinite-dimensional Banach space)
2. The statement regarding infinite products also holds without the Hausdorff assumption (see for example Theorem 16 in Kelley).

My question is about the remaining statement about topological groups, which I'm not very familiar with:

Could anybody please provide a proof? Is the Hausdorff assumption necessary here and can compactness be weakened to relative compactness?

In other words, I'm looking for the weakest condition on a topological group such that every (relatively) compact subset is nowhere dense

**Edit**: The proof of the accepted answer below (with a slight and straightforward modification*) shows that every relatively compact subset of a non-locally-compact Hausdorff topological group is nowhere dense.

- A relatively compact subset which is not nowhere dense has an interior point, of which the closure of the subset is a compact neighbourhood.

Comment: You should add your definition of local compactness for non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @PaulFrost you are of course right, thanks for pointing it out! The conclusion holds without the Hausdorff assumption if relative compactness is defined in terms of compact neighbourhoods. This is enough for my purposes, but maybe it can be generalized to one of the weaker definitions.

Comment: relative compactness of course means local compactness

Comment: In non-Hausdorff spaces your definition of local compactness may have undesirable consequences. You cannot be sure that any neighborhood of a point $x$ contains a compact neigborhood of $x$. Also note that compact subsets are not necesarily relatively compact.

Comment: @PaulFrost Indeed, so the proof below works for Hausdorff topological groups. I have adjusted the edit to my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulFrost Sorry to bother you again but I still don't understand completely, could you please provide more details where things go wrong without the Hausdorff assumption? Isn't it the case that a homeomorphism preserves compactness, no matter if the space is Hausdorff or not? Also, if you start with a relatively compact set $K$, by definition its closure is compact, and if a set is not nowhere dense, then the same is true for its closure. Therefore, the closure again is a  not nowhere dense set and a compact neighborhood of any interior point. From here, the proof should go through as before.

Comment: 1. Yes, homeomorphisms preserve compactness. 2. A set is nowhere dense if its closure has emtpy interior. Thus you are right, the closure of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense. 3. If $K \subset X$ is compact and $\overline K \supsetneqq K$ (which is possible in non-Hausdorff $X$), then I do not see why $\overline K$ should be compact. If you take an open cover of $\overline K$, then $K$ is covered by finitely many members of this cover, but why should **each** point of  $\overline K \setminus K$ be contained in one of these members?

Comment: Your edit concerning relatively compact subsets is not correct, but this does not matter. Here is the correct argument: Given a relatively compact subset $C$ which is not nowhere dense, then the compact set $K = \overline C$  has an interior point $x$ of which $K$ is a compact neighbourhood.

Comment: @PaulFrost I understand now, my problem was to ignore the fact that a closure has to be taken because of the definition of (not) nowhere dense. Regarding your last comment (my edit concerning relatively compact subsets): What you write is exactly identical to my edit. In any case, we both mean the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a compact set $K$ is not nowhere dense. Then it has an interior point say $g$.  Note that $K$ is a compact neighborhood of $g$. For any other point $h$ apply the homeomorphism $x \to hg^{-1}x$ to see that $h$ also has compact neighborhood. Hence the space  is locally compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  in fact your proof works for relative compact sets as well (see the edit of my answer)!

Comment: Your proof works only when $K$ is closed. This is true in Hausdorff $X$. If $K$ is not closed, you cannot be sure that $\overline K$ is compact.

Comment: @PaulFrost the title says 'non-locally compact Hausdorff space'. I think this means Hausdorff but not locally compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are of course right. My comment concerned the OP's question "Is the Hausdorff assumption necessary here and can compactness be weakened to relative compactness? In other words, I'm looking for the weakest condition on a topological group such that every (relatively) compact subset is nowhere dense".